# how to pass multiple argument in createRole using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

When i create Role i can able to pass one argument `RoleName` only. if i pass more than one argument it shows error. how to pass multiple argument to insert the table.

```
[HttpPost]
        [MyExceptionHandler]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RoleCreate([Bind(Include = "RoleName,Status,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,ModifiedBy,ModifiedDate")]Role role)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Roles.RoleExists(role.RoleName))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Rolename already exists");
                    return View(role);
                }
                else
                {
                    Roles.CreateRole(role.RoleName, role.Status,role.CreatedBy,role.CreatedDate,role.ModifiedBy,role.ModifiedDate);
                    return RedirectToAction("ViewRole", "Account");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please enter Username and Password");
            }
            return View(role);
        }
```

If i added `Roles.CreateRole(role.RoleName, role.Status,role.CreatedBy,role.CreatedDate,role.ModifiedBy,role.ModifiedDate);` multiple argument showing error

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the enumeration role. The only way to do it is.

```
foreach (Role role in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role)))
{
    Roles.CreateRole(role);
}
```

According to MSDS `CreateRole Method (String)` accepts only one param. It does not have overloadings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.createrole(v=vs.110).aspx